# Typescript: the rules of assertion to partial type

Tags: typescript

```
type Rec = Record<'a', number>

const a: Rec = { b: 1 } 
// Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Rec'

const b = { b: 1 } as Rec
// Error: Conversion of type '{ b: number; }' to type 'Rec' may be a mistake [...]

type PRec = Partial<Rec>

const pa: PRec = { b: 1 }
// Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Partial<Rec>'

const pb = { b: 1 } as PRec
// ALL OK. o_O
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGUC8sEHsBOATAPAcgEM8AaKAOwFcBbAIwgwD4AoeNMgZ2CgIC5VEUAbyg0+ARigBfFm04jkUYaKgTJ3dvyZNQkKAAU4A-QQzAAlgQA2OQ81YcuYXvsMKl4qTIdQwNNyI81Ag0DBC0zMmB6ADMCeGgASUjFbj5KWnpPezkCMz4kriEAlSzZLhozf2VVdSgCrR1oPQKFPRNzKxwCuzKfXL5m5KLq0u9fSuHA2sHgJiA)

Interfaces behave just the same – so I assume it's not because of index signature. It's somehow because of `Partial`.

[Docs](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#how-typescript-determines-if-a-single-assertion-is-not-enough) says, that

> Basically, the assertion from type S to T succeeds if either S is a subtype of T or T is a subtype of S

So, the logic should be: `{ b: 1 }` is a subtype of `{ a?: number }`

But this means, that here `{ a?: number }` is **not** considered as '*an object with `a: number` prop, or an empty object*' – instead, it's '***ANY** object, which occasionally may have `a: number` prop*'.

Does this mean that *optional keys do not restrict the shape of object*? Can I find this in docs, and is it another known issue / technical limitation / assumed compromise / works-as-intended / etc of TS?

Comment: Oof this is a question where the answer could be a book about structural subtyping, optional properties, excess property checking, weak type detection, and rules for assertions.  The short answer is that `{b: 1}` is not considered a subtype of `{a?: number}` because the latter is a [weak type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) but the assertion is allowed because assertions do not perform weak type detection to determine relatedness.

Comment: Would that be sufficient if I wrote it up (and explained more about weak types and relatedness?)  Or do you still wonder why, for example `{b: 1, c: ""}` is a subtype of `{a?: number, c: string}` (the latter is no longer weak and so standard structural subtyping rules apply).  Or do you wonder if `{a?: number}` really places no restrictions on the object, (no, e.g., `{a: ""}` is not assignable to `{a?: number}`)?  Or do you wonder if optional properties are fully consistent (no, `{a?: 0}` is assignable to `{}` is assignable to `{a?: 1}` but `{a?: 0}` is not assignable to `{a?: 1}`). Etc etc

Comment: @jcalz so in the last case, TypeScript doesn't care that {b: 1} is not a subtype of {a?: 1}?

Comment: Maybe it’s best to think of weak type detection as a more restrictive rule for subtyping, and that type assertions act according to a less restrictive rule for subtyping.  Saying “is a subtype” and “is not a subtype” might be too binary for what’s happening.

Comment: @jcalz I would appreciate any extra explanations / examples you can provide. Also, reference to some good book on the topic you mentioned also will be helpful.